# Python Pandas: Re pivot or re groupby using the values as index

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and have been trying to figure out how to re-pivot or re-groupby using the output values.  For example my sample csv data which I read in using read_csv below,

```
    Transaction, Product, Dollar_Amount
    A, Orange, 1
    A, Apple, 2
    A, Pear, 3
    B, Orange, 4
    B, Grape, 5
    C, Apple, 6
    D, Orange, 1
    D, Apple, 2
    D, Pear, 3
```

I count the number of products in each transactions using either the following pivot or groupby methods,

```
grp = df.groupby('Transaction').size().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
pivo = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Transaction'], values=['Dollar_Amount'], margins=True, aggfunc=[len]).reset_index()
```

From the output, I then want to pivot or groupby so that I can count the number of transactions within each count of products to get the following output,

```
Count_Products Count_Transactions
1 1 <-- Transaction C
2 1 <-- Transaction B
3 2 <-- Transaction A & D
```

I am at a lost on how to do this 2nd part.  Please help and thanks in advance.

Regards,
Lobbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df.groupby('Transaction').size().reset_index(), index=0, values='Transaction', aggfunc=len).reset_index()
df2.columns = ("Count_Products", "Count_Transactions")
```

Output:

```
Count_Products Count_Transactions
0            1                  1
1            2                  1
2            3                  2
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks so much for the how-to!!!  I didn't know we can nest a groupby inside a pivot.  It worked!  Thanks again.

Comment: btw, how do I sort by Count_Transactions in descending order within your 1st statement or I have write another line of code to sort?  Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be able to add the sort to the end of that first statement

Comment: you beauty! it worked again.  Thanks. I did this df2 = pd.pivot_table(df.groupby('Transaction').size().reset_index(), index=0, values='Transaction', aggfunc=len).reset_index().sort_values(by='Basket', ascending=False)

Answer (score 2):

you can use pipeline

```
result=(df.groupby('Transaction')
          .size()
          .sort_values(ascending=False)
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={0:'Count_Transactions'})
          .groupby('Count_Transactions')
          .sum())
```

almost the same result you want

```
    Transaction
Count_Transactions  
1   C
2   B
3   D A
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for this.  I need the count instead but I will keep this in my favorite code snippets in case I need to output like this in the future.  Thanks again, Lobbie.